# SharePoint Online | Email column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a list in my SharePoint Online site.  The list has a single line of text column for email address.  I want to make the values in this column clickable so that when a user clicks on the value it opens in Outlook.  This is possible if a column is "Hyperlink" type but not if it is "Single line of text".

I have noticed that if a column is single line of text and you add a email address and open it with "Quick Edit", the value in the field is abc@xyz.com.  So, the email should be clickable but when you click on the link, nothing happens.

Do you know if there is a script that can be added to enable this functionality?

Thanks,

Ricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the new [column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) options in O365. On the listview, use the menu for your single line of text and choose **Column Settings** > **Format this column**. This will open the Format column display pane where you can paste the following to have the contents automatically turned into a mailto link.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
    "debugMode": true,
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [{
        "elmType":"a",
        "txtContent":"@currentField",
        "attributes":{
            "href":{
                "operator":"+",
                "operands":[
                    "mailto:",
                    "@currentField"
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```